# How to remove child object from parent object list javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

```
 <script>    var itemsTemp= [
             { id: 0, text: 'Andy' },
             {
               id: 1, text: 'Harry',
               children: [
                 { id: 2, text: 'David' }
               ]
             },
             { id: 3, text: 'Lisa' },
             { id: 4, text: 'Mona' },
             { id: 5, text: 'Ron' },
             { id: 6, text: 'Joe' }
           ];
 
   var items  = itemsTemp;
 
         var filtered = items.filter(function(item) { 
             return item.id !== 3;  
         });
 
         console.log(filtered);
 
 </script>
```

in this way, I can only remove the parent but how can I delete the child object? please help me to fix this

Comment: If you want to remove a member from an object. You can use `delete`.

Comment: Do you need to be able to remove from both parent list and child list or just child list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this.

```js
   var itemsTemp= [
             { id: 0, text: 'Andy' },
             {
               id: 1, text: 'Harry',
               children: [
                 { id: 2, text: 'David' }
               ]
             },
             { id: 3, text: 'Lisa' },
             { id: 4, text: 'Mona' },
             { id: 5, text: 'Ron' },
             { id: 6, text: 'Joe' }
           ]; 
        var items  = itemsTemp; 
        var filtered = items.filter(function(item) {             
             childrens=item.children;            
             if(childrens)
             {
              filteredchildren = childrens.filter(children=>children.id!==2);
              item.children=filteredchildren;
             }
            
             return item.id !== 2;
         });
         console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Working good thank you. How can i remove if have a child componet inside the child componet
 var itemsTemp= [
             { id: 0, text: 'Andy' },
             {
               id: 1, text: 'Harry',
               children: [
                 { id: 2, text: 'David',
                 children: [
                 { id: 20, text: 'David20' },
                ] },
               ]
             },
             { id: 3, text: 'Lisa' },
             { id: 4, text: 'Mona' },
             { id: 5, text: 'Ron' },
             { id: 6, text: 'Joe' }
           ];

Comment: @BiswanathPrasadSingh btw, this solution will only work if your objects are nested two levels deep. This wouldn't handle the case for when `{ id: 2, text: 'David' }` has a `children` array and holds an object with the id you want to remove

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to filter children, you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to perform a mapping and filtering of your array. When you reach an object which has a `children` property, you can recursively call your function to then perform the mapping/filtering on the child array `.reduce()` array like so:

```js
const items = [{ id: 0, text: 'Andy' }, { id: 1, text: 'Harry', children: [{ id: 2, text: 'David' }] }, { id: 3, text: 'Lisa' }, { id: 4, text: 'Mona' }, { id: 5, text: 'Ron' }, { id: 6, text: 'Joe' } ];

const filterItems = (items, fn) => items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(item.children)
    return [...acc, ...filterItems(item.children, fn)];
  else if(fn(item))
     return [...acc, item];
  return acc;
}, []);

const filtered = filterItems(items, item => item.id !== 2);
console.log(filtered);
```

If you don't want to remove the item from the parent list, and only from the child list, then you push an update object instead:

```js
const items = [{ id: 0, text: 'Andy' }, { id: 1, text: 'Harry', children: [{ id: 2, text: 'David' }] }, { id: 3, text: 'Lisa' }, { id: 4, text: 'Mona' }, { id: 5, text: 'Ron' }, { id: 6, text: 'Joe' } ];

const toRemoveId = 2;
const filterItems = (items, fn) => items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(item.children)
    return [...acc, {...item, children: filterItems(item.children, fn)}];
  else if(fn(item))
     return [...acc, item];
  return acc;
}, []);

const filtered = filterItems(items, item => item.id !== 2);
console.log(filtered);
```

This will work for arbitrary object depths.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote the filterById function I think it works for your case

```js
var itemsTemp = [
  { id: 0, text: "Andy" },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Harry",
    children: [{ id: 2, text: "David" }],
  },
  { id: 3, text: "Lisa" },
  { id: 4, text: "Mona" },
  { id: 5, text: "Ron" },
  { id: 6, text: "Joe" },
];

var items = itemsTemp;

const filterById = (items, id) => {
    return items.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if(currentValue.children){
          const newCurrentValue = filterById(currentValue.children, id)
          currentValue = {...currentValue, children: newCurrentValue}
        }
        if(currentValue.id !== id){
          return [...accumulator, currentValue]
        }
        return accumulator
    },[])
}

console.log(filterById(itemsTemp,2));
console.log(itemsTemp)
```

Comment: Yes I just update the way it won't modify the original object. As filterById we can dynamic the id better than just filter by fixed ID.